# Interpretation of ZINB when ziformula = ~1 in glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I estimated a ZINB model with the probability of producing a structural zero as equal for all observations with ziformula = ~1. For context: I want to know what predicts the number of cigarettes smoked per day (CPD) over 20 days.

```
zinb <- glmmTMB(CPD ~ 1 + day + X2*X3*X4 + X5*X6*X4 + X7 + (1 + day + X2||ID), 
data = data, ziformula=~1, family="nbinom2")
```

I got the following output for the zero-inflated part:

```
Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.2626     0.1117   -11.3   <2e-16 ***
```

1. I know that the count model has a log link function in which I have to use exp() to get the rate ratio (please correct me if wrong). I also know for the zero-inflated model that I have to calculate exp(-1.27) = 0.28 and that 0.28 means the probability of having a structural zero. This already confuses me a little because I thought when I have a logit link function (which there is in the zero-inflated part) I have to use plogis(-1.27) but I repeatedly read that I have to use exp(-1.27)? Any explanation there?

2. What I am also confused about is, since I have longitudinal data, if this probability for the zero-inflated part is only for day 1 or is it for all days? How it's written in Brooks et al. (2017) that the ziformula = ~1 means "the probability of producing a structural zero as equal for all observations" confuses me. And also: is the value of exp(-1.27)=0.28 a rate ratio, odds ratio, or what is it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well we found out that the Intercept of the zero-inflated part can be interpreted as a rate ratio. What still is unclear is the first part of question 2); if the two parts of the model are independent, meaning if the intercept can be interpreted over all days or only for day 1 since I don't have a time variable in the formula for the zero-inflation?